# How user space memory and kernel space memory is mapped to physical memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I can guess, this question might be duplicate, but just for clarity, I am asking it separately.

So What I understand is, for 32 bit architecture, we have 4 GB virtual memory, In which 3 GB is used for user space and 1 GB for kernel space.

So what I don't understand is, the same 1 GB physical memory is shared between user space processes and kernel space, How it works exactly ?

Please let me know if question is not clear, I will try to add more details.

Comment: This is off topic. Perhaps it belongs on superuser?

Comment: From an application's point of view, you should not care. Each process runs in virtual memory & has its own address space.

Answer (score 4):

> So What I understand is, for 32 bit architecture, we have 4 GB virtual memory, In which 3 GB is used for user space and 1 GB for kernel space.

Right. Each process has 3GB for process-specific mappings in virtual memory. The kernel has 1GB for its virtual mappings.

> So what I don't understand is, the same 1 GB physical memory is shared between user space processes and kernel space, How it works exactly?

The operating system manages all physical memory, mapping it into kernel virtual memory or user virtual memory as needed. If process X needs physical memory page Y mapped at virtual address Z, then the kernel will ensure that mapping is in place when process X runs.

Comment: So does it mean process never touches that 1 GB of kernel virtual addresses ?

Comment: A process running in user space cannot directly access any of the kernel's mappings. In theory, the kernel could give a process permission to access some portions of those mappings, but I don't believe it ever does. (There may be a few exceptions, such as a read-only mapping of a page that contains configuration and/or status information.)

Comment: *"The operating system manages..."* -- Perhaps mentioning the salient HW involved in the mapping, the MMU, should have been squeezed somewhere into your answer to a question of *"How it works exactly"*.